# How to show an entire div on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help displaying a div with a form inside of it whenever someone selects a certain option from a  tag. My code is this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#contactOptionSelect').change(function() {
                    $('.emailForm').hide();
                    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
                });
            });

    </script>
        <div class="contactSelect" id="contactOptionSelect">
            <label for="selectContact">Contact us: </label>
            <select name="selectContact" class="selectContactType" style="width: 150px;"/>
                <option class="opt" value="">Please select</option>
                <option class="opt" id="helpOpt" value="">Help and Support</option>
                <option class="opt" id="emailOpt" value="">Email</option>
                <option class="opt" id="visitOpt" value="">Visit us!</option>
                <option class="opt" id="phoneOpt" value="">Phone</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
        <div class="emailForm" id="emailFormId">
            <form id="contactUsForm" method="post" action="">
                <div class="formSubject">
                    <label for="inputSubject">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" width="50px" id="inputSubject" />
                </div>
                <div class="formBody">
                    <label for="inputBody">Email</label>
                    <textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="inputBody"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="formSubmit">
                    <input type="submit" id="inputSubmit" value="Send!"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And I want to display the last form when the email option is selected. I kinda want it to work like this: http://www.apple.com/privacy/contact/ High standards I know but whatever haha Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The animations themselves are really easy to do these days with libraries like jQuery/jQuery UI.  The high-gloss look and feel is going to be the difficult part to get on par with, yet remain distinct (not look like an apple clone).  They employ lots of designers :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsbin.com/okakuy/edit#javascript,html

Whenever the select option is changed, we hide whichever `div` is visible, and show whichever `div` has the current select value as its `id` attribute.

```
$("#parts").on("change", function(o){
  $(".panels")
    .find("> div:visible")
      .slideUp()
    .end()
    .find("#" + o.target.value)
      .slideDown();
});
```

Coupled with this markup:

```
<select id="parts">
  <option>foo1</option>
  <option>foo2</option>
  <option>foo3</option>
</select>
<div class="panels">
  <div id="foo1">This is foo1</div>
  <div id="foo2">This is foo2</div>
  <div id="foo3">This is foo3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but it seems your implementation might be a little weird.  Is there a way to force only one or two of these animations to work at a time?  If you use the keyboard to flip between options very quickly, you'll see that all 3 animations could be active at the same time, which might cause layout issues when there is more content in the divs.  A bit nit-picky, but it seems the apple site interrupts animations and immediately disappears the corresponding div when you switch between them.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham You can swap the effect from `slideUp` to `hide`, and from `slideDown` to `show` to remove any parallel animations.